# Is it possible to configure JAX-RS method with variable number of URI parameters?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

is it possible to configure GET method to read variable number of URI parameters and interpret them either as variable argument (array) or collection? I know query parameters can be read as list/set but I can't go for them in my case.

E.g.:

```
@GET
@Produces("text/xml")
@Path("list/{taskId}")
public String getTaskCheckLists(@PathParam("taskId") int... taskId) {
    return Arrays.toString(taskId);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the `@Path` annotation can take a regular expression to specify a list of path components. For example, something like:

```
@GET
@Path("/list/{taskid:.+}")
public String getTaskCheckLists(@PathParam("taskid") List<PathSegment> taskIdList) {
    ......
}
```

There's a more extensive example [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html).

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the closest I'll get to that so now I just need to put there regexp that matches numbers and slashes for example.com/ws/list/1 or example.com/ws/list/1/2/3/4/5/6

Answer (score 3):

I am not submitting this as an answer as it is merely an edge case on the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3632863/274677) which is what I've also used.
In my case (Jersey 1.19) `/list/{taskid:.+}` would not work for the edge case of zero variable parameters. Changing the RegEx to `/list/{taskid:.*}` took care of that. See also [this article](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.2.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#_Path_and_regular_expression_mappings) (which seems to be applicable).

Moreover, upon changing the regexp to cardinality indicator to `*` (instead of `+`) I also had to deal programmatically with the case of empty strings as I would translate the `List<PathSegment>` into a `List<String>` (to pass it into my DB-access code).

The reason I am translating from `PathSegment` to `String` is that I didn't want a class from the `javax.ws.rs.core` package to pollute my Data Access Layer code.

Here's a complete example:

```
@Path("/listDirs/{dirs:.*}")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response listDirs(@PathParam("dirs") List<PathSegment> pathSegments) {
    List<String> dirs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (PathSegment pathSegment: pathSegments) {
        String path = pathSegment.getPath();
        if ((path!=null) && (!path.trim().equals("")))
            dirs.add(pathSegment.getPath());
    }
    List<String> valueFromDB = db.doSomeQuery(dirs);
    // construct JSON response object ...
}
```