# How to inject HTTP query parameters into beans list or array as method's parameter with JAX-RS by Apache CXF?

Tags: java, rest, cxf, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm learning JAX-RS by making sample webapp, and I have a question
about parameters injection from HTTP request to java method's parameters.

Now, I'm trying to inject query parameters into some beans on 
sample JAX-RS project , named 'cxftest01' using Apache CXF ,
which is supposed as HR management in a company.

So, I got started to make some beans classes following class 'Employee'

---

```
package com.sample.cxftest01.beans;

public class Employee {
    private Name name;
    private String division;

    public Name getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(Name name) { this.name = name; }
    public String getDivision() { return division; }
    public void setDivision(String division) { this.division = division; }
}
```

---

and next class 'Name'

---

package com.sample.cxftest01.beans;

```
public class Name {
    private String first;
    private String last;

    public String getFirst() { return first; }
    public void setFirst(String first) { this.first = first; }
    public String getLast() { return last; }
    public void setLast(String last) { this.last = last; }
}
```

---

and JAX-RS resouce class is next.

---

package com.sample.cxftest01.restapi;

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.sample.cxftest01.beans.Employee;

@Component
@Path("employees")
public class EmployeeResource {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response getPerson(@QueryParam("") Employee employee)
    {
        return Response.ok(employee, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ).build();
    }
}
```

---

These codes above worked. When I accessed URL,

```
http://localhost:8080/cxftest01/employees?
    name.first=Joe&name.last=Hayek&division=SoftwareDevelopment
```

on address bar in my web borowser(I use latest Chrome), the browser displayed next JSON.

```
{"name":{"first":"Joe","last":"Hayek"},"division":"SoftwareDevelopment"}
```

Next, I planed following senario. If I'll give 2 employees in query parameters like

```
name.first=Joe&name.last=Hayek&division=SoftwareDevelopment&
name.first=Meg&name.last=Tanaka&division=Sales
```

then I'll be glad to get next JSON as result,

```
[
    {"name":{"first":"Joe","last":"Hayek"},"division":"SoftwareDevelopment"},
    {"name":{"first":"Meg","last":"Tanaka"},"division":"Sales"}
]
```

So, I modified the method EmployeeResource#getPerson() as following:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getPersons(@QueryParam("") List<Employee> employees)
{
    return Response.ok(employees, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ).build();
}
```

And I tried to access next URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/cxftest01/employees?
    name.first=Joe&name.last=Hayek&division=SoftwareDevelopment&
    name.first=Meg&name.last=Tanaka&division=Sales
```

, but the borowser displayed next error message.

**Class java.util.List can not be instantiated**

So I ask next two points.

1) What is the reason why the error indicated by the message above was happened ?

2) If you know how to inject query parameters to beans list or array as a
  parameter of some methods in JAX-RS resouce class, as my senario
  explained above, please teach me.

Best regards.

Comment: to configure your service with a list, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629225/is-it-possible-to-configure-jax-rs-method-with-variable-number-of-uri-parameters