# REST auto resources creation

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm trying to find a way to automatically create REST Resources. I have a number of REST resources created but I knew in advance how many they were going to be, things like /users/{userId}, ect.

What I'm facing now is, a user uploads a url like a/b/c and I need to have a,b,c accessible thru REST.

The user could upload a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h 
the rest resources created would be /data/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h

or something like:
school/teachers/teacherId/classes/Math/firstClass
and it would create
data/school/teachers/teacherId/classes/Math/firstClass

It depends on the user and it can't predict how much resources the user creates.

Is there a way around this?

Thank you in advance for your help

Technologies: Java + Jersey (Jax-RS)

Comment: Why is the number of resources a problem?

Comment: I don't know how to make jersey react to a variable number of resources and with each resource name variable aswell...

Right now I have things like:
/apps
apps/appId/
apps/appId/users

Its all things I know in advance and whose order does not change. How would I set up the system to react properly to:
/data/school/teachers/teacherId/classes/Math/firstClass

or 
/data/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h
or
/data/vehicles/cars/convertibles/brands

Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629225/is-it-possible-to-configure-jax-rs-method-with-variable-number-of-uri-parameters) answer may help you.

Comment: You are absolutelly right Pyranja. If it wasn't for you I would still be struggling with it. It worked fine, I will post an answer to this question and give credit both to you and for @DaveRay.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Pyranja and @DaveRay I managed to get it working. Incase someone needs to do it, here is the solution for the above example:

```
@GET
@Path("/{pathId:.+}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getPathOfElements(@PathParam("pathId") List<PathSegment> pathList) {
    System.out.println("I got in.");
    for(int i = 0; i < pathList.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(pathList.get(i).getPath());
    }
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(appId).build();
}
```