# How to display a collection with multiple id's?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs, restful-url

I have a collection of people with id's assigned to them. I want the user to have the Ability to retrieve people collection using multiple ID's ( 0 to many).I can do this if I have one id as the parameter:

```
@Path( "{people/id}" )
@GET
public PeopleDTO findOne ( @PathParam( "id" ) int id ) {
    return PersonDAO.findOne( id );
}
```

How do I write a similar method where user can specify multiple id's and that will retrieve info for that many people? 
Or to say it differently, I want to output collection of people accepting filter for 0...* IDs.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629225/is-it-possible-to-configure-jax-rs-method-with-variable-number-of-uri-parameters)

Comment: You are welcome. Google more next time before posting question on SO.

Comment: Please, please, the answer in that link is a _horrible_ solution for this problem. You are making the URI completely unRESTful if you do this. Trying to do something like `.../people/1/2/4/5/6/7` to identify a subset of the parent collection is just ugly. Use a query parameter to filter the parent collection instead.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not trying to access a single resource, then you are trying to access the collections of resources, only you just want a subset. This is pretty common for things like pagination. For that you can just have a query parameter to filter. For instance you can use

```
.../people?filterIds=1,3,5,6,7,8
```

Then just use `@QueryParam`

```
@GET
@Path("people")
public PeopleDTO getPeople(@QueryParam( "filterIds" ) String id ) {
```

This can be used to get all the people or a filtered list. You just need to parse the string. First check if it's null, if it is, then it's a request for a full list.

You could also may it more object oriented, and use something like `Filtered`

```
@GET
@Path("people")
public PeopleDTO getPeople(@QueryParam( "filterIds" ) Filtered filtered ) {
    String[] values = filtered.getValues();
```

You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30407999/2587435) to see that can be accomplished. Use something like

```
public class Filtered {

    private String[] values;
    public String[] getValues() { return values; }
    public void setValues(String[] values) { this.values = values; }

    public static Filtered fromString(String param) {
        if (param == null) return null;

        Filtered filtered = new Filtered();
        filtered.setValues(param.split(",");
        return filtered;
    }
}
```